How update Parquet file after reading from it - refreshByPath not working
I need to persist certain information into parquet file to be accessed and updated during one batch job or the next (e.g. average values, slopes etc).
I created a little test for a prototype:
class TestStateManagement:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def init_test(self, spark_unit_test_fixture, tmp_path):
        self.spark = spark_unit_test_fixture
        self.path = tmp_path
        

    def test_double_safe_parquet(self):
        schema = StructType([StructField("time", IntegerType()), StructField("value", DoubleType())])
        dataframe = self.spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0)], schema)
        parquet = os.path.join(self.path, "test.parquet")
        dataframe.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(parquet)
        dataframe = self.spark.read.parquet(parquet)  # this cause problem! 
        assert dataframe.count() == 3

        dataframe_add = self.spark.createDataFrame([(4, 4.0), (5, 5.0), (6, 6.0)], schema)
        self.spark.catalog.refreshByPath(parquet)
        dataframe.union(dataframe_add).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(parquet)

This test yields:
E                   Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkFileNotFoundException: File file:/....snappy.parquet does not exist
E                   It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

The problem is caused by the read in between. I need it because i want to be sure to always read the newest. After the test (the 2nd write) the parquet file disappears.
As stated in title adding self.spark.catalog.refreshByPath(parquet) is not helping. Is there another way to refresh or make this work?

The issue is that you write to same path as you read the data
dataframe = self.spark.read.parquet(parquet)            
dataframe.union(dataframe_add).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(parquet)

these 2 rows of code cause error
it would work fine if you write it to tmp path
dataframe.union(dataframe_add).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(tmpPath)

and then read it from tmp path and write back
spark.read.parquet(tmpPath).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(parquet)

upd:
Overrite - means overrite the output location.
It is not possible in spark to read and then write to same loction in 1 spark job.
That is because of how spark works internally.
It is evaluated lazily on any active action, in your case it starts evaluation when you call write method.
In few words it builds execution plan splitting job in stages and tasks.
As spark is distributed system, any node can go down. In such case it can recompute data stored on this node.
Think now, in your case if you read and write to same directory, what should happen? :)
Should it take partially written data to recompute? Which will output wrong result.
So, to handle it - it validates that source files where not changed (after it built execution plan) and fails if change detected.

ok, but what is use of "overwrite" then?

@dermoritz check upd section in my answer

Since this is a test case, just use cache when reading it:
dataframe = spark.read.parquet(parquet).cache()  # Worked like charms!

Let me know if you face any issue.

That will not work, or if works, can lead to weird bugs, cache can be evicted and then recalculated again anytime when spark thinks it has not enough memory. Also cache does not truncates execution plan. To resolve this, instead of cache better to persist it to some tmp path and then read it.

That's why I said just for test case

Typical SO answer: You're doing it wrong. :-).
Why write two different dataframes to same location? Write to different folders. Also what's the purpose of second write? There are no assertions. In tests usually you'll do:
import tempfile

class TestStateManagement:

    def test_double_safe_parquet(self, spark_unit_test_fixture):
        schema = 'time:int, value:double'
        df = spark_unit_test_fixture.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0)], schema)
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
            df2_dir = f'{tmp_dir}/df2'
            
            df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(df2_dir)
            df2 = spark_unit_test_fixture.read.parquet(df2_dir)
            assert df2.count() == 3

            df_union_dir = f'{tmp_dir}/df_union'
            df_add = spark_unit_test_fixture.createDataFrame([(4, 4.0), (5, 5.0), (6, 6.0)], schema)
            # no assertions?
            df.union(df_add).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(df_union_dir)



the purpose is to update the data i write. it stores data that i want to read and use in another batch or in another step of transformations. For example i need the last n values to calculate a slope. this values i store in parquet - to be read if needed and updated
