Pyspark write "delta" has side effect on dataframe written if dataframe was previously read with delta
I am implementing kind of a state store for my pyspark pipelines. For this i chose delta lake to save and restore the state - mainly very small dataframe that may be updated and read multiple times during current batch (spark session) and across batches.
On first tries all works fine using this methods.
load state:
def load_state(self, state_id: str, id: str):

    path = os.path.join(self.state_folder, state_id, msn)

    if DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(self.spark, path):
        return self.spark.read.format("delta").load(path)
    else:
        return self.spark.createDataFrame([], StructType([]))

save state:
def save_state(self, state_id: str, id: str, new_state: DataFrame):


    path = os.path.join(self.state_folder, state_id, id)

    write_options = {
        "overwriteSchema": "true",  # allows schema evolution
        "deltaLog.deleteAllCheckpoints": "true"  # delete all checkpoints avoid new ones on write
    }

    isolated_df = new_state.select("*").cache()
    isolated_df.count()

    (isolated_df.write.mode("overwrite")
     .options(**write_options)
     .format("delta").save(path))

    isolated_df.unpersist()

This has a problem if "new_state" was created via load state (needed to update states).
after the write operation new_state has additional rows - the rows from previous state copied within the dataframe.
As you see i tried hard to isolate "new_state" from any side effects. but it is not working: after the write (before unpersist) - both isolated_df and new_state are changed.
So my first question is: is there a way to really isolate the given "new_state" to prevent any side effects?
More general: ** How to keep an unchanged copy / state of a dataframe and be able to materialize / safe as Delta the dataframe at any point**
(like a wire tap)
The only solution i currently have is using side effects on top: I read back the just written delta and manipulate "new_state":
def save_state(self, state_id: str, msn: str, new_state: DataFrame):
    """
    Saves/ overwrites the state for the given MSN.

    :param state_id: identifies the state to be saved
    :param msn: identifies the aircraft
    :param new_state: state to be saved, will overwrite existing state
    :return:
    """

    path = os.path.join(self.state_folder, state_id, msn)

    write_options = {
        "overwriteSchema": "true",  # allows schema evolution
        "deltaLog.deleteAllCheckpoints": "true"  # delete all checkpoints avoid new ones on write
    }

    (new_state.write.mode("overwrite")
     .options(**write_options)
     .format("delta").save(path))

    read_back = self.spark.read.format("delta").load(path)
    new_state._jdf = read_back._jdf
    new_state._schema = read_back._schema

This is working as intended - but feels very bad. Performance wise and code wise.
So i highly appreciate any better solution (preventing side effects on new_state - also on calling side)
For sake of completeness a test that fails due to side effects:
def test_state_manager(self):
    # ... test setup
    
    new_state = self.spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0)], schema)
    state_manager.save_state(state_id, "pc24_666", new_state)

    loaded_state = state_manager.load_state(state_id, "pc24_666")
    assert loaded_state.count() == 3

    new_state1 = self.spark.createDataFrame([(4, 4.0), (5, 5.0), (6, 6.0)], schema)
    updated_state = loaded_state.union(new_state1)
    
    assert updated_state.count() == 6
    state_manager.save_state(state_id, "pc24_666", updated_state) # now updated state changed

    update_read = state_manager.load_state(state_id, "pc24_666")

    assert updated_state.count() == update_read.count() #  while update_read is correct holding 6 entries updated_state holding 9 - each row of new state copied


you are misunderstanding concept of DataFrame. It does not hold data, it is algorithm of how to transform data from the source until the given DF. For example, when you do .load(path) in load_state, no data is loaded into the memory. It just remembers where is data source. Think of DataFrame as of lazy stream (like Java stream) - nothing will be read until you call collector function.

If you want to keep some rows set in the memory, call df.collect() - it will bring all rows into the memory.

my problem is: i want save my state to delta independently of other operations i want to onto dataframe (later). i know that write will materialize - but i want to keep a copy that not materializes yet to perform further operations. but caching and persiting the given data frame seem not to help?! - why to persist/ cache at all?
added - a more general question

Explanation for you 6 vs 9 - new_state is algorithm which remembers it consists of two sources - delta path and union with in-memory dataframe. During save you do cache/unpersist, but it happens on isolated_df not on outer updated_state. When you do last assert then for updated_state it reads two sources, as it remembered - 6 from delta and 3 from union

Not sure if it is good solution but you can try changing your load_state into .load(path).cache() - it should prevent re-reading source. However, it is advice not strict instruction so Spark is free to drop cached data if there is memory pressure

the count of updated_state only changes on write (writing a different cached dataframe). if i don't write you see assert updated_state.count() == 6 is passing. so write on different dataframe changes - i want to prevent this - isolate the write


IMHO you're better off just saving state as a text (csv, json) file rather than a Delta table. You're using none of the features of Delta table. You're deleting checkpoints, overwriting schema, overwriting data, always reading whole table.

Problem is (as Alexander Pavlov pointed out), Dataframe is lazy load. So you need to force the execution of plan with something like collect(). E.g. code below creates an isolated replica dataframe (df2) from original dataframe (df).


You might be forced to waste time updating this code if you want a generic function that supports crazy complex schemas with complex nested types etc. Also collect() is slow, brings all data to the driver RAM. Which is why I recommend #1.
>>>
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0)], schema='id:int, value:double')
>>> df.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  1.0|
|  2|  2.0|
|  3|  3.0|
+---+-----+

>>> rows = df.collect()
>>> col_order = df.columns
>>> my_schema = df.schema
>>> dicts = [r.asDict() for r in rows]
>>> data = [[d[c] for c in col_order] for d in dicts]
>>>
>>> data
[[1, 1.0], [2, 2.0], [3, 3.0]]
>>> my_schema
StructType([StructField('id', IntegerType(), True), StructField('value', DoubleType(), True)])
>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=my_schema)
>>> df2.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  1.0|
|  2|  2.0|
|  3|  3.0|
+---+-----+

>>>


Your function can be changed as:
def save_state(self, state_id: str, id: str, new_state: DataFrame):
  path = os.path.join(self.state_folder, state_id, id)

  write_options = {
    "overwriteSchema": "true",  # allows schema evolution
    "deltaLog.deleteAllCheckpoints": "true"  # delete all checkpoints avoid new ones on write
  }

  isolated_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[d[c] for c in new_state.columns] for d in [r.asDict() for r in new_state.collect()]],
    schema=new_state.schema
  )

  (isolated_df.write.mode("overwrite")
   .options(**write_options)
   .format("delta").save(path))


can you please explain why using just collect or in my case count is not enough? why i need to go through coulmn by column?
And delta lake write is executing the plan - the question is why this changes df?
Is your approac better than mine - just reading in the state again (i guess some file cach will be in place)?
i thought i am forcing execution by doing count(). What feature i am using is (parquet failed here) is concurrent Reads/ writes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78810176/how-update-parquet-file-after-reading-from-it-refreshbypath-not-working this i fixed by using delta lake.

Matter of opinion, but this is still a very serious misuse of Delta tables. It's pretty easy to create your own lock files and achieve this. count() doesn't execute the plan in many cases (I've observed). I don't even trust collect() to do that fully (Row might be lazy), which is why I convert it to python primitives before creating the new DF.

@Kashyap Delta stores a lot of information in delta log including number of rows. If you query .count() without filters then it even does not have to load data files, it gets everything from the log. Row is fair thing, you can trust it :)

@AlexanderPavlov, yes, "count() doesn't execute the plan in many cases" was more in general, irrespective of underlying source. Sources like Delta keep metadata, some others don't.

Thanks to comments here i found a solution. The solution lies for whatever reason in read_state.
The problem described occurs on write of data (only if data contains parts previously read via delta). The input dataframe of safe_state changed after write even after this kind of isolation:
def save_state(self, state_id: str, msn: str, new_state: DataFrame):


    path = os.path.join(self.state_folder, state_id, msn)

    write_options = {
        "overwriteSchema": "true",  # allows schema evolution
        "deltaLog.deleteAllCheckpoints": "true"  # delete all checkpoints avoid new ones on write
    }

    to_be_written = self.spark.createDataFrame(new_state.collect(), new_state.schema)

    (new_state.write.mode("overwrite")
     .options(**write_options)
     .format("delta").save(path))
   
    #  now new_state changed and has additional columns 
    #  if new_state based on a dataframe previously read through delta

But what helped to decouple the read dataframe:
    if DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(self.spark, path):
        df = self.spark.read.format("delta").load(path)
        # we need to materialize the dataframe to avoid odd side effects on write to the dataframe returned here
        return self.spark.createDataFrame(df.collect(), df.schema)

This works. Now write does not have any side effects back to the read dataframe.
I am still keen to understand this better - especially why isolating on write does not help.

Worth to mention this only works for datasets which can fit into driver's memory

thanks - in my case i use this as a state storage. This will only contain very small datasets - sometime only single numbers
